# selection sort algo does not correctly sort numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a selection sort algorithm in C++. Whenever I run the program, it does not sort the list properly in ascending order. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void swap(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB) {
    int tmp = arr[indexA];
    arr[indexA] = arr[indexB];
    arr[indexB] = tmp;
}

int main() {
    int list[] = { -4, 36, -200, 57, 3, 1, 1000, 353, 234, 435, -21353, 90324 };
    int minIndex = 0;
    int n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) { //move boundary one step at a time until you're at second to last elmnt
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if (list[j] < list[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        swap(list, i, minIndex); //swap min elmnt of the list 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << list[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you compared your code to any one of the dozens of implementations out there on the web?

Comment: Remember that you don't merely want to *sort*. You want to *selection sort*. This means you have to closely adhere to the rules of selection sort. Normally I'd say something like, *the programmer's secret weapon ins the debugger*, but this could lead you to a program that sorts without implementing selection sort. Do what jarmod suggested, and if you have confirmed your implementation matches what a credible site like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) describes and it STILL doesn't work, then step through the program with a debugger and see where the program deviates.

Comment: Don't edit the question to include the answer. Either select the answer that led you to the solution as the correct answer or write an answer explaining the problem and solution if there are no helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is missing a step.  The minIndex needs to be set at the start of each i loop.

Comment: `j = i;` also starts `j` at the wrong spot. Probably still sorts, but at a cost of an extra variable considered.

Comment: j should start at i+1.  If j=i, it just means it does one more iteration than required.